# Spark Error:- "value foreach is not a member of Object"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, databricks

The dataframe consists of the two columns (s3ObjectName, batchName) with tens of thousands of rows like:-

| s3ObjectName | batchName |
| --- | --- |
| a1.json | 45 |
| b2.json | 45 |
| c3.json | 45 |
| d4.json | 46 |
| e5.json | 46 |

The objective is to retrieve objects from an S3 bucket and write to datalake in parallel using details from each row in the dataframe using foreachPartition() and foreach() functions

```
  // s3 connector details defined as an object so it can be serialized and available on all executors in the cluster

object container {
  
  def getDataSource() = {
    val AccessKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "ADBTEL_Scope", key = "Telematics-TrueMotion-AccessKey-ID")
    val SecretKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "ADBTEL_Scope", key = "Telematics-TrueMotion-AccessKey-Secret")
    val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey)
    val clientRegion: Regions = Regions.US_EAST_1
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withRegion(clientRegion)
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .build()
    
  }
}

dataframe.foreachPartition(partition => {
      //Initialize s3 connection for each partition
      val client: AmazonS3 = container.getDataSource()
      partition.foreach(row => {
        val s3ObjectName = row.getString(0)
        val batchname = row.getString(1)
        val inputS3Stream = client.getObject("s3bucketname", s3ObjectName).getObjectContent
        val inputS3String = IOUtils.toString(inputS3Stream, "UTF-8")
        val filePath = s"/dbfs/mnt/test/${batchname}/${s3ObjectName}"
        val file = new File(filePath)
        val fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)
        val bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
        bw.write(inputS3String)
        bw.close()
        fileWriter.close()
        })
      })
```

The above process gives me

> Error: value foreach is not a member of Object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert Dataframe to RDD before calling `foreachPartition`.

```
dataframe.rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {

})
```

Comment: converting to rdd worked, I now get a java.lang.NullPointerException when executing my logic and might need to start a separate thread for that. Thanks. I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: how did you resolve the null pointer exception? I am facing the same issue on doing a ```row.getAs[String](columnName)```

Comment: If you have null values in column, don't use `getAs`. Use `get('colname')` and put null check condition before calling `toString`.